# Can slf4j handel multiple logging frameworks simultaneously?

Tags: java, slf4j

Lets say an application developer wants to use a library utilizing log4j and a library utilizing java.util.logging for his application. Can slf4j help him to "unify" logging in this case? Is a "unification" desriable in this situation at all?

I know that the libraries SHOULD have been written using slf4j and that the application developer then could have decided to for instance ONLY use log4j in the back-end. I'm new to logging and trying to understand the advantages of slf4j in different situations, though.

Best regards, Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see the documentation on [Bridging legacy APIs](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html). In a nutshell, you pick one logging library to be your "real" implementation. For the others, use an SFL4J bridge like `jul-to-slf4j` or `jcl-over-slf4j` (note that the java.util.logging bridge requires some extra configuration which is described in the linked docs). The bridge library emulates the API of the legacy logging library and routes the calls to your "real" logger.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer.

Comment: You are most welcome :-) If this answer solved your problem, you can encourage me by marking it as "accepted".